# How can I programmatically know which interface orientaton I am in when the application loads?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

Using some of the methods, I am able to check the orientations to which I am rotating my device. But how can I know the orientation in which I am in when the app is loaded? I want to write the code to rearrange the views in the viewDidLoad method by checking the way my orientation is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIDeviceOrientation myOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something similar to below in the ViewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear methods.

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
}
```